# Validar minutos en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta y en el calculo de varias columnas saco la diferencia en minutos entre dos horas dadas.

```
    SELECT KE.HRZMX(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(SDDP AS varchar),1,4),'-'), CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(SDDP AS varchar),5,2),'-')),
CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(SDDP AS varchar),7,2),' '), CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(STD AS varchar),1,2),':')), SUBSTRING(CAST(STD AS varchar),3,2))) FechaProg,
KE.HRZMX(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(DATDEPP AS varchar),1,4),'-'), CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(DATDEPP AS varchar),5,2),'-')),
CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(DATDEPP AS varchar),7,2),' '), CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(HRDEP AS varchar),1,2),':')), SUBSTRING(CAST(HRDEP AS varchar),3,2))) FechaReal,
CODAVION, NROVOL, CASE WHEN APD = 'PNG' THEN 'PDS' WHEN APD = 'TNY' THEN 'TPQ' WHEN APD = 'COL' THEN 'CLQ' WHEN APD = 'TMN' THEN 'TSL' ELSE APD END AS Orígen, 
CASE WHEN APA = 'PNG' THEN 'PDS' WHEN APA = 'TNY' THEN 'TPQ' WHEN APA = 'COL' THEN 'CLQ' WHEN APA = 'TMN' THEN 'TSL' ELSE APA END AS Destino,
CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(STD AS varchar),1,2),':'), SUBSTRING(CAST(STD AS varchar),3,2)) HoraSalPrev,
CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(HRDEP AS varchar),1,2),':'), SUBSTRING(CAST(HRDEP AS varchar),3,2)) HoraSalReal,
CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(HRDEPABOP AS varchar),1,2),':'), SUBSTRING(CAST(HRDEPABOP AS varchar),3,2)) HoraDespegue,
CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(HRARRABOP AS varchar),1,2),':'), SUBSTRING(CAST(HRARRABOP AS varchar),3,2)) HoraAterrizaje,
CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(HRARR AS varchar),1,2),':'), SUBSTRING(CAST(HRARR AS varchar),3,2)) HoraLlegReal,
CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(STA AS varchar),1,2),':'), SUBSTRING(CAST(STA AS varchar),3,2)) HoraLlegPrev,
PAXEMB1 Pasajeros, PAXMAX Capacidad, ISNULL(PAXEMB1,0) / PAXMAX LF,
DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(STD AS varchar),1,2),':'), SUBSTRING(CAST(STD AS varchar),3,2)), CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(HRDEP AS varchar),1,2),':'), SUBSTRING(CAST(HRDEP AS varchar),3,2))) DemoraSalida,
DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(STA AS varchar),1,2),':'), SUBSTRING(CAST(STA AS varchar),3,2)), CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(HRARR AS varchar),1,2),':'), SUBSTRING(CAST(HRARR AS varchar),3,2))) DemoraLlegada,
IIF(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(STD AS varchar),1,2),':'), SUBSTRING(CAST(STD AS varchar),3,2)), CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(HRDEP AS varchar),1,2),':'), SUBSTRING(CAST(HRDEP AS varchar),3,2)))>0,'Demorado', 'A Tiempo') TipoDemoraSalida,
IIF(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(STA AS varchar),1,2),':'), SUBSTRING(CAST(STA AS varchar),3,2)), CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(HRARR AS varchar),1,2),':'), SUBSTRING(CAST(HRARR AS varchar),3,2)))>0,'Demorado', 'A Tiempo') TipoDemoraLlegada,
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(STA AS varchar),1,2),':'), SUBSTRING(CAST(STA AS varchar),3,2)), CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(HRARR AS varchar),1,2),':'), SUBSTRING(CAST(HRARR AS varchar),3,2))) BETWEEN 5 AND 9 THEN 'ATD+5'
WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(STA AS varchar),1,2),':'), SUBSTRING(CAST(STA AS varchar),3,2)), CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(HRARR AS varchar),1,2),':'), SUBSTRING(CAST(HRARR AS varchar),3,2))) BETWEEN 10 AND 14 THEN 'ATD+10'
WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(STA AS varchar),1,2),':'), SUBSTRING(CAST(STA AS varchar),3,2)), CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(HRARR AS varchar),1,2),':'), SUBSTRING(CAST(HRARR AS varchar),3,2))) > 15 THEN 'ATD+15' ELSE 'ATD+0' END AS ATD,
DATEPART(HOUR,KE.HRZMX(CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(STD AS varchar),1,2),':'), SUBSTRING(CAST(STD AS varchar),3,2)))) HoraSalPrev
FROM KE.Vuelos2
```

En la teoría funciona bien con excepción de los siguientes ejemplos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La diferencia debería de ser solo 60 minutos ya que se demoro una hora pero lo está tomando como si fuera  otro día y coloca una diferencia de 1380 minutos.

Comment: Pregunta: ¿esos CONCAT anidados qué valor crean? Es decir, estás haciendo el DATEDIFF pero, ¿sabemos con certeza qué valores está comparando? Es que sin datos no es nada evidente. Disculpa.

Comment: Los dos primeros anidan una fecha completa y todos los demás anidan diferentes horas y minutos. Esa es la función de los CONCAT

Comment: PD. Te recomiendo que revises si en todas las preguntas que has hecho, las respuestas que te han dado han resuelto esas preguntas. De las últimas diez has aceptado respuestas para dos y no has dicho ni comentado por qué sirven o no sirven para tu pregunta. Es una gran señal de que no das feedback a quienes intentamos responderte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás comparando sólo horas (`hh:mm`) al construir cada valor como

```
DATEDIFF(
    MINUTE,
    CONCAT(
        CONCAT(
                SUBSTRING(CAST(STA AS varchar),1,2),
                ':'
        ), 
        SUBSTRING(CAST(STA AS varchar),3,2)
    ), 
    CONCAT(
        CONCAT(
                SUBSTRING(CAST(HRARR AS varchar),1,2),
                ':'
        ), 
        SUBSTRING(CAST(HRARR AS varchar),3,2)
    )
) DemoraLlegada,
```

y ese `datediff` no tiene información para saber si corresponden a fechas diferentes, consecutivas, al mismo día, a días diferentes, etc. Pásale a `datediff` un datetime o una fecha-hora completa.

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME2 = '2007-05-04 23:55:09.3312722';  
DECLARE @enddate   DATETIME2 = '2007-05-05 00:10:09.3312722';   
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, @startdate, @enddate);
```

Esto da 15.

Si simplifico eso a tu formato actual:

```
DECLARE @startdate TIME = '23:55:09';  
DECLARE @enddate   TIME = '00:10:09';   
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, @startdate, @enddate);
```

Me da -1425. En general, todos los datediff que tienes operando sobre horas son susceptibles a problemas similares.

PD. [CONCAT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) es capaz de recibir N parámetros, así que un enredo como el que tienes puede simplificarse como:

```
 DATEDIFF(
    MINUTE,
    CONCAT(
           SUBSTRING(CAST(STA AS varchar),1,2),
           ':',
           SUBSTRING(CAST(STA AS varchar),3,2)
    ), 
    CONCAT(
           SUBSTRING(CAST(HRARR AS varchar),1,2),
            ':', 
           SUBSTRING(CAST(HRARR AS varchar),3,2)
    )
) DemoraLlegada,
```

Y si armas una expresión T-SQL, puedes hacer el CAST una sola vez y simplificar ese script significativamente (junto con varias mejoras más). Lo notarás en el tiempo de ejecución (y en el uso de CPU). Pero todo eso es para otra pregunta (o para tu curiosidad).